# Restricted ManyToMany relationships in Django

Tags: django, django-admin, foreign-key-relationship, m2m

I'm hoping someone can point me to the most Djangoic way to represent the following general relationship with models, so that Django's existing logic naturally enforces the relationship.

Thing A and Thing B both have one of a number of Types. Thing A can be related to many, one, or no Things Bs and vice-versa (in a symmetric fashion), however Thing A and Thing B can be related if and only if they share the same Type.

My current implementation is to have three models, A, B, and Type, where As and Bs have a foreign key to Type, and A has a m2m with B.

```
class A(models.Model):
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)
    typ = models.ManyToManyField(Type)

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)

class Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

This lets me do what I want, but doesn't *enforce* the fact that A can't have a B of another Type. I can use filtering logic in views I control, but where I have less control, like in the Admin, Django lets me map As to Bs of different Types. Is there another way to represent the relationship between As, Bs, and Types in Django?

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach off the top of my head:

```
class A(models.Model):
    typ = models.ManyToManyField(Type)

    @property
    def related2B(self)
        return list of relationships

    def save
        check that relationship is still valid if typ field changes

class B(models.Model):
    typ = models.ManyToManyField(Type)

    @property
    def related2A(self)
        return list of relationships

    def save
        check that relationship is still valid if typ field changes

class Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()


class Relationship(models.Model):
    classA = models.ForeignKey(A)
    classB = models.ForeignKey(B)

    def save
        do check that they share a type before saving
```

Comment: the model save method shall not do a save/no save choice, this often cause issues in related items saving. Because saving a related object if you don't have id crashes, etc..

Comment: You can have the Relationship as an inline to A and B, this will take care of saving.  In the model save, you just need to get the saves in the right order:  do test for valid, call super to save, now you have id and can save related.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.limit_choices_to) as a way to control the scope of the M2M?

It can take Q objects for complex queries, but am guessing not F ones (for complex queries including the parent object's current state), but you still might be able to make it deny the save if inappropriate

Comment: limit_choices_to is evaluated when the model is defined and doesn't look at properties of a particular model instance. I don't think it can be used to check Thing A's Type and limit_choices_to Thing Bs that have that same Type.